The edges of the baked low-poly normal map are not smooth and are jagged
I am trying to bake a normal map of a sculpted body model on retopologized low poly model. Unlike to tutorial video on youtube(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zxl38NpPWdo&list=PL6B1Babb0QiM5TQ6HlrI2OavuXnsMuO-O&index=136) my baked normal map divided by tiles of retopology. The border should be smooth and not choppy, but my result is not like that. I followed the steps in the tutorial video exactly, but what did I set up wrong?
